# Scrapy parse is returning an empty array, regardles of yield

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am brand new to Scrapy, and I could use a hint here. I realize that there are quite a few similar questions, but none of them seem to fix my problem. I have the following code written for a simple web scraper:

```
import scrapy
from ScriptScraper.items import ScriptItem

class ScriptScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "script_scraper"

    allowed_domains = ["https://proplay.ws"]
    start_urls = ["https://proplay.ws/dramas/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for column in response.xpath('//div[@class="content-column one_fourth"]'):
            text = column.xpath('//p/b/text()').extract()
            item = ScriptItem()
            item['url'] = "test"
            item['title'] = text
            yield item
```

I will want to do some more involved scraping later, but right now, I'm just trying to get the scraper to return anything at all. The HTML for the site I'm trying to scrape looks like this:

```
<div class="content-column one_fourth">
  ::before
  <p>
    <b>
      All dramas
        <br>
        (in alphabetical
        <br>
        order):
    </b>
  </p>
...
</div>
```

and I am running the following command in the Terminal:

```
scrapy parse --spider=script_scraper -c parse_ITEM -d 2 https://proplay.ws/dramas/
```

According to my understanding of Scrapy, the code I have written should be yielding the text "All dramas"; however, it is yielding an empty array instead. Can anyone give me a hint as to why this is not producing the expected yield? Again, I apologize for the repetitive question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your XPath expressions are not exactly as you want to extract data. If you want the first column's first-row item. Then your XPath expression should be.

```
item = {}
item['text'] = response.xpath ('//div[@class="content-column one_fourth"][1]/p[1]/b/text()').extract()[0].
```

The function extract() will return all the matches for the expression, it returns an array. If you want the first you should use extract()[0] or extract_first().
Go through this page https://devhints.io/xpath to get more knowledge related to Xpath.